# What is the difference between the different GloVe models?

Tags: nlp, deep-learning, stanford-nlp

https://nlp.stanford.edu/projects/glove/

I'm trying to use GloVe for summarizing music reviews, but I'm wondering which version is the best for my project. Will "glove.840B.300d.zip" give me a more accurate text summarization since it used way more tokens? Or perhaps the Wikipedia 2014 + Gigaword 5 is more representative than Common Crawl? Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately I don't think anyone can give you a better answer for this than:

"try several options, and see which one works the best"

I've seen work that uses the Wikipedia 2014 + Gigaword 100d vectors that produced SOTA results for reading comprehension.  Without experimentation, it's difficult to say conclusively which corpus is closer to your music review set, or what the impact of larger dimensional word embeddings will be.

This is just random advice, but I guess I would suggest trying in this order:

100d from Wikipedia+Gigaword
300d from Wikipedia+Gigaword
300d from Common Crawl

You might as well start with the smaller dimensional embeddings while prototyping, and then you could experiment with larger embeddings to see if you get a performance enhancement.

And in the spirit of promoting other group's work, I would definitely say you should look at these ELMo vectors from AllenNLP:

http://allennlp.org/elmo

They look very promising!

Comment: Thank you very much! That was what I had assumed, but I was wondering if there was a practical reason for using those corpora. As in, perhaps the researchers already had in mind what types of datasets would work best with it. I'll be taking a look at the ELMo vectors. Btw, have Stanford researchers tried using RL yet? Similar to what Metamind did https://einstein.ai/research/your-tldr-by-an-ai-a-deep-reinforced-model-for-abstractive-summarization

Comment: There was RL for recent coref models, but not for summarization.